# jQuery change value of input field when created

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I want to change the value of an input field when it's created using jQuery.
The element appears when clicking on an "Add"-Button. The browser then performs a GET call and the following element appears:

```
<tr class="edit add"><td class=""><input id="SupplierOrderingTime_Time" name="SupplierOrderingTime.Time" value="00:00:00" type="text"></td>
```

I'm currently solving it with a little timeout so the element can be detected using a normal selector:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var time = $("#SupplierOrderingTime6 .tablesorter tbody td").first().text();
    $("#SupplierOrderingTime_Time").attr("value", time);
}, 250);
```

It does the job but I'm looking for a better way that does it immediately when the element is created.

Comment: Can you show us what happend when click "Add", I mean can you show your code?

Comment: Which code you mean? The ajax call when clicking on "Add"?

Answer (score 0):

When you send the Ajax -GET function. set the `async` option to be false. So the callback will run before latter code.

Comment: I don't want to change the GET function because I'm working on a Greasemonkey script and don't want to insert this method in order to change it. If this is the only way to do it, I think it's better I stick with the current solution.

Comment: I think so. currently this maybe the only "better" way.